# Using Inkscape and printing on larger paper than canvas

Tags: print-design, inkscape, borders, canvas

Wondering how to print (to scale 1:1) on larger paper than the canvas. Currently, when I print (using larger paper, but not changing printer setup, so it thinks it still canvas sized) a border of about 1/2" all the way around is missing its content. I have tried selecting a larger paper size in page setup, but that causes the print to be scaled, and it still does not print the content at the edge of the canvas.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Printing to the edge of sheet (or borderless printing) is most often a function of the printer and not software. Is your printer capable of borderless printing?

Comment: it's a regular laser printer. I get that it cannot print to the border, but I am using larger paper than the canvas, and would like it to come out unscaled and the entire canvas printed..

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not making sense to me. You do not want to scale anything, but you want a *smaller* piece of art to fill a *larger* piece of paper? How do you imagine that happening *without* scaling in some manner?

Comment: I don't want the image to scale; i want to take advantage of the fact I am printing on larger paper, and print all the stuff near the border of the canvas that is not printing. Nothing larger than the canvas needs to print, but I want everything on the canvas to print... the canvas is 7x12", but only an area of roughly 6x11" is printing. My print paper is legal 8.5x14"

Comment: Set the print output to the ACTUAL paper size.. then print at 100%. If the art doesn't fill the paper size, then it's printed at 100% with no clipping.

Comment: That might work, I will try it for a test template, however I will be sending the output to a laser cutter and it will expect the canvas to be the actual size of the material I will be cutting (7x12")

Comment: You don't need to alter the canvas. You merely need to alter the print settings to tell it to use the proper paper size, that's all. (You edited and added more detail as I was editing `:)` )

Comment: ok, i selected manual scaling of 100%, so it prints to scale on the larger paper, but the borders are still cut off, i guess the correct term is clipped!

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but I enlarged the canvas (+1x1") and centred everything. the full drawing now prints. I can drop the canvas back to actual size for the final cut.

Answer (score 0):

Set the print output to the ACTUAL paper size.. then print at 100%. If the art doesn't fill the paper size, then it's printed at 100% with no clipping.